# Не работают стили CSS в html

Tags: html, css

Код в html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="txt/css" href="lesson0.css">
        <title>CSS урок 0</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Код в CSS:

```css
body{
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: путь правильный к файлу? lesson0.css находится вместе с index.html ?

Comment: да,они находятся в одной папке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если файл CSS находится в отдельной папке к примеру CSS то путь должен быть

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lesson0.css" />`

Если файл рядом с файлом html то попробуй назвать файл 1.css и в пути файла тоже не забудь переименовать. Возможно ошибка в каком-то символе в названии пути (такое тоже бывает).

Comment: Спасибо. Проблема была скорее всего в этом. Но я также удалил эту часть type="txt/css". И всё заработало